# How to make UIImage navigate to another ViewController?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Is it possible to make `UIImage` navigate to another `ViewController` when I tap on it ? 
Just like `UIButton`.

Thanks.

Comment: You can put the tapgesture on UIImage then handle that gesturen

Answer (score 3):

ya you can use

```
var tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("imageCliecked"))
yourimageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
yourimageView.userInteractionEnabled = true // this is must dont forget to add
```

method is

```
func imageCliecked()
{
println("Tapped on Image")
// navigate to another 
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("yoursegueName", sender: self)
}

   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender:AnyObject?)
  {
  if segue.identifier == "yoursegueName" {

  var destViewController: ViewController = segue.destinationViewController as ViewController

  destViewController.img = imageView.image // pass your imageview
   }

   }
```

**another ViewController**

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController 
{

 strong var img: UIImage!

 override function viewDidLoad()
 {
  if(self.img)
  self.imageView.image = img;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
//add gesture recogniser

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(navigate)];
tap.delegate=self;
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];

//call method
-(void)navigate{
    //call the navigation ..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your question I have tried below solution.Also it works fine.

```
  override func viewDidLoad() 
  {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    var tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "navigationFromImage:")

    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1

    imageviewNavigation.userInteractionEnabled = true

    imageviewNavigation.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

  }

 func navigationFromImage(sender: UIGestureRecognizer)
 {

    var secondViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("navigatingSecondViewController") as SecondViewController

    secondViewController.globalImage = imageviewNavigation.image!

    navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
              //OR

    presentViewController(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

 }
```

Also in Storyboard click the required view controller

```
     1.Go to or click show the Identity inspector
     2.Click Identity
     3.In StorybordId you must give "navigatingSecondViewController" or whatever you want.
     4.Finally you must give same name in your storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("navigatingSecondViewController")
```

in SecondViewController

```
   var globalImage: UIImage = UIImage()

   override func viewDidLoad() 
   {

      super.viewDidLoad()

      // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

      imageAccess.image = globalImage
   }
```

Comment: the "imageviewNavigation" is supposed to be the name of my image outlet right ?

Comment: Yeah.That is imageView outlet.Whatever you want to set your image view name,just give here.Just I set image view name as a imageviewNavigation.That is it.

Comment: okay thanks, now after I click Ctrl and swipe in storyboard from my image to the new view controller the image doesn't seem to let me add this

Comment: how I would create an identifier for this image and this view controller if image doesn't let me add one

Comment: In Next View Controller again you have to set the image View like previous View Controller Outlet  ImageView.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92243/discussion-between-user3182143-and-hussein-reda-albehary).

Answer (score -2):

yes it is possible to navigate one controller to another controller using property...

e.g.

```
// second Controller.....(you pass image on this controller)
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface NewScreen : UITableViewController
{

}
@property(strong,nonatomic)UIImage *yourImage;
@end


/// First Controller where you pass your image...

- (IBAction)convertVideoButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    NewScreen *objNew=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NewScreen"];
    objNew.yourImage=imageNamed;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:objNew animated:YES];
//  NSURL *videoPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"part1" ofType:@"mov"]];
//  [self convertVideoToMP4:videoPath];
}
```

Comment: Err this is pushing a view controller on tap of an unknown UIView, and sets Image to the second controller. I think OP was asking on how to push a new controller on tap of `UIImage`